# How to add selected/over in ImageView with a xml selector in Android 2.2 with only one image? like add opacity or alpha

Tags: android, xml, hover

I want to create an over or selected appearence with only one image.
Not programatically, but in xml selector.
Sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

try this, Create selector.xml in your drawable like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/hover_image" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/hover_image" android:state_focused="true">/item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_bg"></item>

</selector>
```

And use like this in your layout xml

```
  <Button

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"

            android:text="@string/notification"
             />
```